# How to find the moment of inertia of the Viking capsule?

Tags: mars, physics, viking

I have an assignment where I have to simulate a Mars re-entry using the Viking capsule. I have finished it but now I want to go further and try to make my capsule glide. For this I need to enslave the path angle which needs the moment of inertia $J$ according to the formulas given by my teacher.

After reading a lot of reports by NASA, I'm beginning to despair of finding that moment of inertia... Maybe I can calculate it using simplification but my domain is more computer science than mechanics.

My question is: Where can I find the moment of inertia? If I need to calculate it, how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

From [Viking '75 Spacecraft Design and Test Summary Volume 1: Lander Design](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19810001592.pdf) page 76

Comment: Perfect thanks!

Comment: @LouisEtienne You are most welcome, and welcome to space stack exchange!