# Was the Space Shuttle balanced experimentally before flight?

Tags: space-shuttle, payload

Even spacecraft that are designed and optimized for a single mission need to be carefully balanced experimentally, and have ballast added before flight.

- [Why did New Horizons have to be spin-balanced to grams-level precision? (With quarters!)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21101/12102)
- [Balancing Perseverance Mars Rover; couldn't they just "move stuff around a little" rather than add 6+ kg of dead weight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43746/12102)
- [How to find the moment of inertia of the Viking capsule?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43717/12102)

The Space Shuttle was reusable and had a comparatively short turn-around time, each time with a different payload.

Was the shuttle's mass distribution or at least its moments of inertia *measured* pre-flight? If so was ballast ever added then to balance it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "experimentally" but the final step before moving the Orbiter out of the Orbiter Processing Facility (OPF) was to weigh it.

> The final step in OPF orbiter processing is weighing the orbiter and
>   determining its center of gravity. Vehicle performance is affected by
>   both the orbiter’s weight and its center of gravity, and flight
>   programming requires accurate measurements.

[Space Shuttle Orbiter Processing Fact Sheet](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/167429main_OrbiterProcessing08.pdf)

Ballast was added or removed to the Orbiter during OPF processing based on the calculated vs. desired mass properties.  Ballast boxes were located in the nose gear wheel well and just in front of the body flap aerosurface hinge.

[image]

(personal notes, annotated by me)

If the weight and balance as measured was different from that predicted, I am sure they would have done something about it.

Comment: Okay, they measure the "monopole moment" *experimentally* rather than theoretically, which would be to add up a long list of masses of every object.

Comment: @uhoh, yeah, they did both. There was a long document called the Vehicle Summary Weight Statement (you can see some in this book https://archive.org/details/nasa_techdoc_19830069020/page/n1/mode/2up) that listed what everything was supposed to weigh. And then the actual measurement in the OPF.

Comment: What are "mass properties"? Do you know if it's the fraction of the weight that would be on the front wheels when it lands, or the absolute weight on them? Or is it more related to moments of inertia or location of center of gravity during flight? Should that be a new question?

Comment: @uhoh "mass properties" is a generic term for weight, moments of inertia, etc. Unfortunately the only reference I know of for how this weighing was actually done costs $20 and I'm not that into it. https://www.sawe.org/papers/1559/buy  Pity, that.

Comment: not the same, but at least free: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/24327072_Determination_of_shuttle_orbiter_center_of_gravity_from_flight_measurements

Comment: Kind of irrelevant to the OPF, sadly.

Comment: Yes it seems so. I was hoping there might be a hint of a comparison to "known values" measured on the ground. It's at least interesting to read in terms of the experiment and microgravity effects (gravity gradients, drag, etc.).

Comment: @uhoh note this old Viking info uses the term "mass properties". https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43721/6944

Comment: the author of your link is `Fraley, J. G.` and that name along with the term "mass properties" is found on original page number 272  of this Engineering Innovations article: https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/584733main_Wings-ch4g-pgs270-285.pdf

Comment: Ugh, the book I was most disappointed in, *Wings in Orbit*.