# How 'space ready' was space shuttle prototype Enterprise?

Tags: space-shuttle, shuttle-enterprise

I have long believed that Enterprise was just an empty craft, with only the instruments to operate in shorts flights in the atmosphere.
Basically a large glider with odd wings.

However, I have been seeing Enterprise referred to as not space-rated or space-ready, and sometimes as an 'orbiter'. (For example [Space Shuttle Orbiter Approach and Landing Test: Final Evaluation Report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19780011246.pdf) that is linked in @OrganicMarble's answer calls it "Orbiter 101" a few times)

This makes it seem like Enterprise was actually a complete Space Shuttle, but missing some testing or without a few required space elements.

**How much of a prototype actually was Enterprise?**

It apparently did not have engines, but the other shuttles also needed to refurbish the engines after each flight.

Comment: I think I've been guilty of referring to Enterprise as an orbiter when talking about the shuttles as a fleet; it's a bit awkward to say "STS orbiters-and-gliders". I don't think I realized before now how appropriate it was that the "pretend spaceship" was named after a "pretend spaceship!" (--and I say this as a lover of Star Trek).

Comment: @RussellBorogove This is where I saw Enterprise being called an orbiter https://www.quora.com/Why-wasnt-the-space-shuttle-Enterprise-ever-sent-into-space

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your belief was pretty correct.

Major systems missing on Enterprise:

- orbital manuvering system
- reaction control system
- main propulsion system
- space radiators
- airlock
- star trackers
- thermal protection system (tiles)
- cryogenic tankage for fuel cell reactants
- payload bay payload mounting hardware
- galley
- aft and overhead windows
- Ku-band antenna

Major systems different on Enterprise:

- hydraulics
- electrical
- thermal control
- cockpit controls and displays
- structure
- communications

Enterprise-only systems

- nose-mounted air data probe
- high pressure tankage for fuel cell reactants
- flight test instrumentation
- umbilical to 747 mothership
- tracking beacons
- ram air scoop

She was intended only for testing the final stages of aeroflight<sup>1</sup>  so had only systems required for that installed.

<sup>1</sup>  The original plan was to convert her into a spaceworthy orbiter by adding the missing systems but it ended  up being too expensive, largely because of structural design changes to the wings, mid-fuselage, and thrust structure. Challenger was built out of the structural test article instead.

[image]

[image]

References

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Enterprise#Differences_between_Enterprise_and_future_shuttles) (partial list)
- *Space Shuttle*, Jenkins, 1992 edition, p. 138 and 147
- [Space Shuttle Orbiter Approach and Landing Test: Final Evaluation Report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19780011246.pdf)

Comment: Are those lead ballasts in the first figure present in the space rated orbiters too or are they to simulate the weight of missing components?

Comment: Definitely the latter, but the operational Orbiters had ballast too: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43749/6944  Enterprise almost certainly had extra.

Comment: Did Enterprise have good life support? 
Or things like crew beds and a toilet?

Comment: @Speedphoenix I looked for details on the life support system but none of the references really mentioned it :( That "ram air" thing probably took the place of some of it. I would guess you are correct on all counts but I try not to put stuff in answers unless it's backed up by references.

Comment: I think it would be relevant to mention how the Enterprise was actually flown. Was it mounted onto an airplane, flown to a high altitude, then disconnected for independent flight?

Comment: @luther Welcome to the site! This site is a little different than many others on the internet. It adheres to a strict question and answer format, and isn't for discussions. The question here was, rightly, very specific, and got a very specific answer. Side issues such as you mention would not be an answer to this question. However, anyone can ask a question, and if you'd like to ask a new question about the drop tests, that would be great.  There are a number of questions about the drop tests here already, search for the tag 'shuttle-carrier-aircraft'.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: I have to disagree. The question is about how space-ready the Enterprise was. Discussing the full extent of its flight capability would, in fact, be a direct answer. Maybe there's some jargon there that I'm missing, but I don't see such a discussion in this answer.

Comment: @luther It's always interesting to see the fresh viewpoints people bring to the site.  You can, of course, write your own answer.

Comment: My own comment was intended to get at what I think is the core of what the OP is asking. If I made my own question, it would just be restating this one.

Comment: I did notice that. That doesn't mean we shouldn't make further comments or that you're not allowed to edit your answer. BTW, I'm not new to StackExchange. If there's a misunderstanding here, I can only guess it has something to do with terminology related to space exploration.

Comment: @luther Thank you for the concern! 
I was however only asking about how/why Enterprise couldn't go to space, not about its usage inside the atmosphere. Your comments do raise the topic of dropping regular Space Shuttles from the carrier aircraft though! I just posted this question about that https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45416/29286.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, your answer does not address how Entreprise would have been on the pad or with the stack. Did it have the components needed like the other Shuttles?

Comment: @Speedphoenix sure, it could be mounted on the ET. It was used to fit-check the facilities. Here's a good artlcle with pictures showing it on the pad.  https://www.nasa.gov/feature/40-years-ago-space-shuttle-enterprise-rolls-to-the-pad/ No main propulsion system plumbing though.